# VS Code, расширение RUST: не работает опция "Run test" (прикрепил скриншот)

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

На картинке выделил красным что именно не работает и там же можно видеть ошибку, которую пишет терминал.
Такая ошибка даже с крейтами, генерируемыми Cargo по умолчанию по команде
*"cargo new hello --lib"*.
Проблем с запуском тестов по команде в терминале "cargo test" нет - этот способ работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного разобрался: для тестирования имеет значение открыта ли корневая папка крейта в левом проводнике EXPLORER.
На скрине видно что я получил ошибку из-за того что в проводнике открыта папка "RUST" где много крейтов, соответственно не выбран конкретный крейт ("Hello" в данном примере). Достаточно неожиданное для меня поведение редактора, в виду того, что я запускаю тестирование из файла, местоположение которого могло бы определяться логикой редактора без опоры на директорию установленную пользователем в EXPLORER.
Если кто-то знает какими настройками повысить дружественность редактора к тому чтобы EXPLORER можно было устанавливать не только в корневое положение крейта и при этом сохранять возможность тестирования, буду благодарен за подсказку. Но что-то мне подсказывает что это не реализовано.